# Função VLOOKUP não funciona no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, google, planilha, fórmula

Estou fazendo fórmulas nas *Planilhas Google*, mas ao fazer uma formatação condicional está informando que a fórmula está incorreta.

```
=VLOOKUP(C3; Concursos!C3:H5; 1; FALSE)
```

Todas as células contêm números inteiros.

Comment: Você esta tentado pesquisar um determinado valor na planilha excel?

Comment: Tente usar ponto e virgula " ; " no lugar das virgulas " , ".

Answer (score 0):

Use a função `PROCV` para pesquisar um valor em uma tabela.

**A sintaxe é:**

```
PROCV(valor_procurado; matriz_tabela; núm_índice_coluna; [intervalo_pesquisa])
```

**Explicando melhor:**

> =PROCV(Valor que você deseja pesquisar; intervalo no qual você deseja pesquisar o valor; o número da coluna no intervalo contendo o valor de
>   retorno; Correspondência Exata ou Correspondência Aproximada –
>   indicado como 0/FALSO ou 1/VERDADEIRO).

**Por exemplo:**

```
=PROCV(B3;A2:C7;2;FALSO)
```

Leia mais em: [Função PROCV](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/procv-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-procv-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: @EliseuB.não entendi.